# execute cmd/shell command - get the output from cmd/shell - run a function on the output - and execute the answer in the same cmd/shell session

Tags: python, shell, cmd, subprocess

thanks in advance for anyone who can help.

flow:

1 - execute the command in cmd or shell # done successfully

2 - get the output from the command # done successfully

3 - run the output by some function # done successfully

4 - execute the answer back to that same cmd/shell session # this is where I fail

5 - get the output of the second command # this is where I fail

this is what I have so far

```
with Popen("COMMAND", stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, shell=True, universal_newlines=True) as p:
   for line in p.stdout:
      expression+=line
  result = ## some function returning var "result"
```

### tried the follwing codes

### tried this one

```
  out = p.communicate(input=result)[0]
  print (out)
```

### tried this one too

```
  out , errs = p.communicate(input=result)
  print (exp)
  print (out)
```

### and this one

```
  print (p.communicate(input=result)[0])
```

all of them didnt worked
tried also with pexpect - was even worse

Comment: You probably don't want to do this.  It's certainly possible, but you will have to deal with buffering and all sorts of subtle issues.  _Why_ do you want to do this?  In particular, why do you need to run the commands in `cmd`, and why does the second command need to run in the same `cmd` process?

Comment: So your first cmd is printing the 2nd cmd as string?

Comment: @ChrisLam yes, the 2nd cmd prints a string which is in the output resulting from the 1st cmd

Comment: @SvenMarnach its a connection to remote computer, the remote computer says something after the 1st command and I need to respond with text found in the output of the 1st command, and after the 2nd command I need to grab the output again.

in a simple explanation:
1-run a command
2-grab the output
3 - run a command (in the same cmd/shell/terminal session)
4- grap the output again

Comment: This is not something you'd do with `shell=True`. You're not running a single command via `cmd /c`. You need an interactive shell by running cmd.exe directly, with all 3 standard handles redirected to pipes. cmd itself will work fine like this, but if you're running external programs they will probably use full buffering on their stdout or disable interactive mode because a pipe isn't a tty -- unless they have command-line options like Python's -i (force interactive) and -u (disable buffering).

Comment: @eryksun the part with `shell=true` and running cmd.exe, I understand.
but the rest of what you wrote I dont know how to implement, can you please specify some reference to what or where to look for how to do what you mentioned ? thank you

Comment: Programs will switch to fully buffering (typically 4 KB) stdout if they detect that it's a pipe or disk file, instead of a character file such as a console screen buffer. Usually there's no option to disable this. It shouldn't be a problem if you're just running an external program as a non-interactive command. The problem occurs when you want to interact with the program, such as Python's shell. Fortunately in the case of Python, there are options to force interactive mode and disable buffering.

Comment: How do I force interactive mode and disable buffering ? It's done with the subprocess library?

Comment: There is no general way to disable buffering or force interactive mode. It's in the design of the external program. When you're running python.exe as the external program, I already mentioned it has -i and -u command-line options to control this behavior. Other programs such as cmd.exe always use line buffered output for their interactive shell, even if stdin and stdout are pipes.

Comment: I'm not sure we are on the same page. Can you please show me an example using what you mentioned above for doing something like that ? I appreciate your help